# .getSize() is updated in a JScrollPane but not in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

The original question was why does not .getSize() return the actual size of a JCompnent after the component has been resized: [.getSize() isn't updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470530/getsize-isnt-updated)

Instead I added, in this case a JPanel, inside a JScrollPane and used scrollRectToVisible() to update getSize(). Consider this small example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Test extends JFrame implements MouseWheelListener{
    JPanel p,p2;
    JScrollPane js;

    Test(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        p = new JPanel();
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        p2=new JPanel();
        p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        p2.setBackground(Color.green);

        p.add(p2);
        js = new JScrollPane(p);

        add(js);

        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Test();
    }
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

        System.out.println(p2.getSize());

        p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        p2.revalidate();

        p2.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(1,1,1,1));

        System.out.println(p2.getSize());
    }
}
```

After I scroll the mousewheel one click the green square is resized. The program also prints out the correct size. However, if I remove the scrollRectToVisible(1,1,1,1) **the square is resized** but **it prints out the wrong size**. The questions are:

1. Is there another way than calling scrollRectToVisible in order to update getSize()?
2. What if it the square is not added inside a jscollpane, like the example in  [.getSize() isn't updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470530/getsize-isnt-updated) is there a corresponding update function?

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no problem. The thing is that you call `revalidate()`  which supports **deferred** layout. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29):

> Supports deferred automatic layout.
>
> Calls invalidate and then adds this component's validateRoot to a list
>   of components that need to be validated. Validation will occur after
>   all currently pending events have been dispatched. ...

In particular *Validation will occur after all currently pending events have been dispatched*

This means that the layout of p2 (and thus its size change) will be performed after all pending events have been dispatched, including the current mouse-wheel event.

When you call `scrollToVisibleRect`, it automatically performs the lay out of your component if it is not valid, this is why calling scrollToVisibleRect causes an immediate resize.

If you really need an immediate resize, you can use `doLayout()` on the parent container of `p2` but I don't recommend it as it can be more expensive. `revalidate()` offers the possibility to coalesce events like `repaint()` does.